# Inserting the data in one table with 2 different tables

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Good day! I'm making an Evaluation Questionnaire and trying to insert the `Question_ID` and the `Rating_ID` on the question_rating table but the `Question_ID` and `Rating_ID` are from different tables which are as follows:

Here's my question table:
[image: question table]

Here's my rating table:
[image: rating table]

Here's the table where I insert those ID's:
[image: question rating table]

Here's my questionnaire form:
[image: questionniare form]

Here's my form code:

```
<form method="POST">
                <table class="table table-bordered stick-top">
                    <thead class="text-center" id="data">
                        <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>Questions</th>
                        <th id="try">Rating</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody class="body_data">


                        <?php 
                            $queryQuestion = "SELECT * FROM question";
                            $resultQuestion = $conn -> query($queryQuestion);
                         ?>

                        <?php while ($row2 = $resultQuestion -> fetch_object()): ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $row2 -> Question_ID ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row2 -> Question_Description ?></td>
                            <td>
                            <?php
                            $q1 = "SELECT * FROM rating ORDER BY Rating_ID ASC";
                            $r1 = $conn -> query($q1);
                            while($row = $r1 -> fetch_object()){
                                echo "<input id='radio' type='radio' name='" . $row2 -> Question_ID . "' value='" . $row -> Rating_ID . "'>" . $row -> Rating_ID;
                            }
                             ?>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td> <td><button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit Evaluation</button></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Here's my insert code:

```
  <?php 
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

            $q3 = "insert into question_rating (null, question_id, rating_id)
    select null, a.question_id, b.rating_id
    from  question a 
    cross join rating b ";
            $conn -> query($q3);

        }

     ?>
```

I am still learning programming SQL. Could anyone shed some light?

Comment: why not simply insert them separately as two query? use a transaction to make sure you have them both together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!

Here's my code:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $sql=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from question")or die ("erorr");
        while(list($Question_ID,$Question_Description)=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
        {
            $evl_val=$_POST['radio'.$Question_ID];
            mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO `question_rating`(`Question_Rating_ID`,`Question_ID`,`Rating_ID`) VALUES (null, '$Question_ID','$evl_val')") or die (mysqli_error($connection));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do with a single query using  insert select and select with cross  join

```
insert into  question_rating (question_id, question_rating_id)
select a.question_id, b.rating_id
from  question a 
cross join rating b
```

and if you use  null then you need  3 column for insert  and 3 column for select eg:

```
$q3 = "insert into question_rating (null, question_id, rating_id)
    select null, a.question_id, b.rating_id
    from  question a 
    cross join rating b
```

Comment: @jerico answer  updated ... if you use 3 column for insert you need  3 column fo select  ..

Comment: your tables  question and rating contain some values  ?  try  execute the select query only  with a sqlIDE or a sql console a show me the result  .